# How do I get the local system time in PHP?

Tags: php, time, cron

I'm writing a PHP system and I need to get the system time. Not the GMT time or the time specific to a timezone, but the same system time that is used by the CRON system. I have a CRON job that runs every day at midnight and I want to show on a webpage how long will it take before it runs again.

For example:
Right now it is 6pm on my system clock. I run the code:

```
$timeLeftUntilMidnight = date("H:i", strtotime("tomorrow") - strtotime("now"));
```

The result, however, is "3:00" instead of "6:00". If I run

```
date("H:i", strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

It returns 0:00, which is correct. But if I run

```
date("H:i", strtotime("now"));
```

It returns 21:00, even though the correct should be 18:00.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me try to clarify: if I run date("H:i", time()), it will show me a time that is 3 hours from now. Because of that, strtotime("tomorrow") - strtotime("now") is giving me 3 hours less than correct.

For example, now it is 6pm, and the cronjob will run at 12am, but strtotime("tomorrow") - strtotime("now") is returning 3 hours, because "tomorrow" is 00:00 but "now" is 9pm.

Comment: @JohnWithoutArms Can you update your post with this code please?

Comment: use `time()` instead of `strtotime("now")`

Comment: Using time() instead of strtotime("now") makes no difference, still the same results.

Comment: yes, but time() doesn't have to parse the string "now" and recognize it as the current time

Answer (score 6):

There are many answers, however there is not even one correct at the time of writing.

PHP `time()` function doesn't return the system time, like most folks believe, but it return the PHP localtime, normally set with `date.timezone` in php.ini, or set with `date_default_timezone_set()` within a script.

For instance in one of my servers, PHP time was set to `Europe/Rome`and system time to `UTC`. I had a difference of one hour between system time and PHP time.

I'm going to give you a solution that works for Linux, I don't know for Windows. In Linux the system timezone is set in `/etc/timezone`. Now, this is normally outside my allowed `open_basedir` setting, but you can add `:/etc/timezone` to your list to be able to read the file.

Then, on top of the scripts, that want to get the system time, you can call a library function that sets the script timezone to the system timezone. I suppose that this function is part of a class, so I use static:

```
static function setSystemTz() {
    $systemTz = trim(file_get_contents("/etc/timezone"));
    if ($systemTz == 'Etc/UTC') $systemTz = 'UTC';
    date_default_timezone_set($systemTz);
}
```

To make the matter worse in PHP 5.3.3 'Etc/UTC' is not recognized, while 'UTC' is, so I had to add an if to fix that.

Now you can happily call `time()` and it will really give you the system time. I've tested it, because I needed it for myself, that's why I found this question now.

Answer (score 4):

php's [`time`](http://php.net/time) will return the system time. you can format it with [`date`](http://php.net/date)

if you just want to display the time in the local time of the visitor maybe you're better off using a little javascript

Comment: I tried this, date("H:i", time()) is returning the GMT time, not the local system time.

Comment: are you sure your server time is not set to GMT? are your cron jobs run on the same server as your php scripts?

Comment: The result from the date("H:i", time()) call is the same on both my Windows machine (with system clock set to local time) and on a Linux machine (checked the time with "top", it is the same local time as my Windows machine). The result is the (correct) GMT time, not the local time.

Comment: The CRON jobs are run on the Linux machine where the application is actually deployed. System time is local, but the code still returns GMT time.

Comment: however the question was, how to get the system time, the one of the machine, and your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: This is incorrect, as are most answers here.  `time()` gives the Unix timestamp, which is independent of timezone.  But to find out what date/time that represents, you need to specify a tz.  Formatting it with `date()` will show you a date/time, but it uses the tz configured in `php.ini` (or in PHP code) to do that. That PHP tz has no relation to the operating system tz, which determines when a "midnight" cronjob runs.  I think [@stivlo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050547) and [@JustinVincent's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003310) answers are currently the only correct ones here.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest and most foolproof way to do it:

```
$sys_timestamp = strtotime(exec("date"));
```

Let's not try to spoof it with php, let's just get the real sys time ;)

(Will work on any unix based system)

Answer (score 0):

**[`time()`](http://www.php.net/time)**

will give you the current system timestamp.

[**Manual**](http://de3.php.net/time)

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Comment: However time() will return PHP localtime, not the system (machine) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date/time of the server on which PHP is running using the [`time()`](http://php.net/time) function -- it'll return a timestamp, that corresponds to the current datetime.

It's the system time, on that server -- the same as used by cron.

Comment: time() will return PHP time, not machine time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the GMT time you may want to use `gmtstrftime()`, which will give you the system time but as in GMT. There's more info at https://www.php.net/gmstrftime.

Comment: The time() function IS giving me the GMT time; I don't want the GMT time, I want the current system time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a formatted date:

```
date ('d/m/y h:i:s');
```

will do the trick, there is no need to pass time() into date as it will default to the current system time if no second parameter is supplied.

for more formatting options see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Otherwise you can just use

```
time()
```

To get you the current unix timestamp as others have mentioned.

Comment: I understand that, the problem is that that date() call is giving me the GMT time, which is 3 hours ahead of my system time.

Comment: @JohnWithoutArms, are you sure your server system is not set to GMT? Date() without arguments should give you the current timestamp of the system, no timezone fiddling involved.

Comment: Yes... I was testing on a Windows machine, and the time on the tray is indeed my local time, and not GMT. Thinking this could be a Windows problem, I got my code on a Linux server, checked the time with "top" (it was correct, local time), ran the code and the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$time=date("h:i:s A", strtotime("now"-14));
echo $time;
```

You can adjust the time by changing the number `14` above.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the current time of your system you need to set the correct `date.timezone` in your php.ini file. For example if you are from India then you would write:

```
date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta
```

For Germany, it would be:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

After doing this, `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` will give your current time. For getting your timezone see the [list of timezones supported by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610665/php-default-timezone).

Answer (score 0):

You can current local time via below Javascript and set it in any PHP variable than.

```
    <script>

        // For 24 hours    

        var ct = new Date();
        var hr = ct.getHours();
        var mt = ct.getMinutes();
        if (mt < 10) {
            mt = "0" + mt;
        }
        document.write("<b>" + hr + ":" + mt + " " + "</b>");    


        // For 12 hours (AM / PM)

        var ct = new Date();
        var hr = ct.getHours();
        var mt = ct.getMinutes();

        var ampm = "AM";

        if (hr >= 12) {
            ampm = "PM";
            hr = hr - 12;
        }
        if (hr == 0) {
            hr = 12;
        }
        if (mt < 10) {
            mt = "0" + mt;
        }

        document.write("<b>" + hr + ":" + mt + " " + ampm + "</b>");

   </script>
```