# PHP default timezone

Tags: php, timezone

there is a function in php to set default timezone-

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

but does this need to be called every time in the application, whenever I want to make use of date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but does this need to be called every time in the application, whenever I want to make use of date?

If your application needs a different timezone [than configured in php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone), then yes, you need to call `date_default_timezone_set` in your script.  You will also need to call it if there is no timezone configured in php.ini, though if that is the case, you need to pester your host to fix it.

Comment: What I can do, if I make changes in php.ini, but timezone doesn't change in my php scripts? and date_default_timezone_get is as it was before I change it in php.ini?

Comment: You probably failed to restart the bits controlling PHP after making the change.  Try restarting the web server software (Apache, IIS, whatever).  If you're using FastCGI, restart your process manager *and* the web server software.

Comment: hmm no, I restart my nginx server, that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timezone in php.ini and then not have to worry about calling it in your script each time: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php