# Why does the php 'date' function returns a wrong time (off by ~24 seconds)?

Tags: linux, php, mysql

I have the following small `php` snippet running on a `gentoo` Linux (php version 5.2.10-pl0-gentoo):

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
<?

class TestDaemon {
    public function __construct(){

        while (TRUE){

            unset($aDate);
            exec("date", $aDate);
            print("date(\"d.m.y H:i:s\") yields: ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")." while 'date' yields $aDate[0].\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
$oDaemon = new TestDaemon();
?>
```

And the output produced is as follows:

```
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:27 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:03 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:28 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:04 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:29 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:05 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:30 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:06 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:32 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:07 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:33 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:09 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:34 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:10 UTC 2014.
date("d.m.y H:i:s") yields: 27.03.14 07:05:35 while 'date' yields Thu Mar 27 07:05:11 UTC 2014.
```

As you can see the times are off by approx. 24 seconds. On a different machine (same OS, same version of PHP) I do **not** see such an offset.

What is the reason for this offset? Does this come from leap second differences? Then which system gives the correct time? Why does `php` not use the Linux system time instead?

Also, can this time offset be a source of problems when working with the mysql database on the same system?

Comment: What timezone are you using?

Comment: php `time()` is time zone independent. also could it be possible that the sys date on those two system differ and also last idea what if you compare timestamp instead of formated date ? Sorry for one hour ago I was a bit sleepy

Comment: I do not know how to find the timezone information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the shell running /bin/date is configured to use the "right" timezones and php is configured to use the POSIX-conformant timezones.  The difference now should be 25 seconds, but if the tz data is over two years old then it would be 24 seconds.  For a picture of why visit http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/amsci.html and see the second plot.  The "right" zones follow the green line.  The POSIX zones are required to stop the system clock on every leap second, so they follow the descending staircase of the blue line. [edit to be sure which was using which method]

Answer (score 0):

Why the offset I don't know, but it seems that `php` `date()` uses `time()` function to get a timestamp. `time()` is defined like this:

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

it never says in documentation that it uses System time.

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050547/1195001) the function `time()` uses the `date.timezone` set in `php.ini` or `date_default_timezone_set()`.
So if your system uses a different time zone than your `php.ini` it could explain the difference because php seems to use its own time.

He also propose the following solution to get the real system time if they are not the same:

> I'm going to give you a solution that works for Linux, I don't know for Windows. In Linux the system timezone is set in /etc/timezone. 
> Now, this is normally outside my allowed open_basedir setting, but you can add :/etc/timezone to your list to be able to read the file.  
> Then, on top of the scripts, that want to get the system time, you can call a library function that sets the script timezone to the system timezone. I suppose that this function is part of a class, so I use static:  
>
>
>
> `static function setSystemTz() {
>     $systemTz = trim(file_get_contents("/etc/timezone"));
>     if ($systemTz == 'Etc/UTC') $systemTz = 'UTC';
>     date_default_timezone_set($systemTz);
> }`
>
>    
>
>
>
>
>
> To make the matter worse in PHP 5.3.3 'Etc/UTC' is not recognized, while 'UTC' is, so I had to add an if to fix that.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper one can find that (at least on my system), date uses the clock_gettime with CLOCK_REALTIME as the clock and php is using gettimeofday().  I am not sure why they would be different though other than perhaps the timezone issue you mentioned.

Comment: @StevenD I'm quoting here, and I don't even understand how php can have a time zone with 24sec delay. but maybe it will help in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering your question but there are many different types of time variable on a typical Linux system:

- The internal time of the harware clock (aka RTC or BIOS time), if you have one. This keeps the time when the system is offline, this may be fake and return bad values on a virtual machine, or you might not even have one. See `hwclock`
- The amount of time that has passed since the kernel was started. (`cat /proc/uptime`)
- The external time as provided by an NTP server via `ntpd`.
- The innacuracy of the realtime clock / time source, how much it drifts over time in parts per million between samples. This is set by calls to the kernel. On a system with NTP it will be saved to your drift file (`/var/lib/ntp/drift/ntp.drift` or similar) and the system's time will be smoothly adjusted rather than have time jumps in your logs.
- The number of miliseconds since 1st of January 1970. See `date +%s`
- Your timezone, set in `/etc/localtime`, see `zdump /etc/localtime`
- The current system time, calculated using all of the above plus rules for timezone, leap year, leap second and so on. See `date`

If I had to guess, I'd say that NTP is slowly adjusting your system time to compensate for your skewed realtime clock while PHP bypasses this and snags it from somewhere else.