# PHP & system dates are different

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am getting different dates/times between system and PHP.

**System**:

```
        $ date
        Tue Nov  3 19:16:51 EAT 2015
```

**PHP**:

```
        echo date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
        -> Tue Nov 3 16:16:23 UTC 2015
```

It appears PHP is defaulting to UTC even though the system has a different time zone. How can I make PHP pick system date/time?

Note: I am avoiding hard-coding the timezone, for maintenance reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: set the default timezone using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: I am still getting the PHP date/time in UTC even after valling `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the local system time in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329467/how-do-i-get-the-local-system-time-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no easy (system independent) way of getting system date/time in PHP, but this seems to work:

```
    $timezone = 'UTC';
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
         $timezone = exec('tzutil /g');
    } else {
            $timezone = exec('date +%Z');
    }

    $localTimezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    $myDateTime = new DateTime(date(), $localTimezone);
    echo ($myDateTime->format('D M j G:i:s T Y') );
```

I haven't tested on Windows but on Linux it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this input at the top of your file.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Country');
```

**Example:**
`date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');`

Comment: This means hard-coding tmezone, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should configure each server's `php.ini` where `date.timezone` can be set:

```
; ...

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = 'America/Chicago'

; ...
```

A list of acceptable timezones can be found in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

---

If you'd rather set it on each script here's a platform independent function that sets it:

```
<?php
function setTimezone($OSXPassword = null){

    $timezone = null;
    switch(true){
        //Linux (Tested on Ubuntu 14.04)
        case(file_exists('/etc/timezone')):
            $timezone = file_get_contents('/etc/timezone');
            $timezone = trim($timezone); //Remove an extra newline char.
            break;

        //Windows (Untested) (Thanks @Mugoma J. Okomba!)
        case(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN'):
            $timezone = exec('tzutil /g');
            break;

        //OSX (Tested on OSX 10.11 - El Capitan)
        case(file_exists('/usr/sbin/systemsetup')):
            if(!isset($OSXPassword)){
                $OSXPassword = readline('**WARNING your input will appear on screen!**  Password for sudo: ');
            }
            $timezone = exec("echo '" . $OSXPassword ."' | sudo -S systemsetup -gettimezone");
            $timezone = substr($timezone, 11);
            break;
    }

    if(empty($timezone)){
        trigger_error('setTimezone could not determine your timezone', E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    }

    return $timezone;
}

setTimezone();
?>
```

As you can tell, support for OSX is sketchy.

The only decent way of getting a timezone on OSX is through `systemsetup` which requires super user to run. I *really* hate the practice of storing root's password in a PHP script but I've included the option for completeness - **use with caution, this is a security vulnerability**. On OSX, if root's password is not provided the script will attempt to get it from user input.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the raw system date.  Seemed like the obvious solution.  Here's how I did it:

```
//*** OVERRIDE PHP DATE WITH RAW SYSTEM DATE ****
$sysdate = exec('date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S');
$sysdate = str_replace("_"," ",$sysdate);
$sd = strtotime($sysdate);

$MM = date ("m", $sd);
$DD = date ("d", $sd);
$YY = date ("Y", $sd);
$HH = date ("H", $sd);
$MN = date ("i", $sd);
$SS = date ("s", $sd);
```