# php date() function is showing yesterday's date

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I use date function on php, it is showing yesterday's date. It is an offline testing using xampp. But the timestamp shows the actual date. So, when I am pulling out data input from today's date, it shows nothing.
For example, my code is_

In the following screenshot, the date displayed and the system's date is different.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/054Xg.png)

What should I do to fix this problem?
Thanks for your time...

Comment: Show us your cooooode

Comment: It's always yesterday *somewhere* in the world, except when it's tomorrow.

Comment: In previous test, the code is echo $d=date('Y-m-d');

Comment: Today is 5/15/2018 where I am.  Maybe set the proper timezone.

Comment: if you had read the PHP manual about the function `date()` you would have found a hint about using `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: More pictures please

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is solved by correcting timezone in php.ini in xampp Apache files...

Answer (score 1):

try to set your time zone in php.ini file like this :

```
            date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

you can check list of Supported Timezones [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: I am testing offline. The date is correct in mysql database, datetime stamp, but in php, the wrong date is showing

Comment: the best way to do it is configuring php.ini file  see here  you can also get the date form the /etc/timezone file  see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504467/php-system-dates-are-different

Answer (score 0):

It's the default servertime.

You can change your timezone with `date_default_timezone_set();`.

For example:
`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

Source: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).