# how to take system time and server time while page loading

Tags: php, php-5.6

I want take when i am switched on my system,that time,i want to take that time(SYSTEM TIME) or (SERVER TIME) in php,bcz when user switched on system i want store that time in logintime for login table,how can do

Comment: You can probably use date() function or DateTime class for that

Comment: You didnt even bother to research your question before posting. `date()` is a highly documented function and easily findable through Google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8050547/3548072 Check this link to get the local system time in PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current date and time in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is what you are looking for.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");// 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
```